# Android Studio 3 does not run tests in Spock

Tags: android-studio, gradle, groovy, spock, android-studio-3.0

I updated Android Studio to version 3 and since then all my spock tests, **when in a java module**, do not run when trying to run them from inside the application (right click on groovy folder -> Run 'Tests in groovy'). I get a:

> Class not found: "*package.name.classname*"Empty test suite."

Same if I try to run a single test.

If I run the *test* task from the gradle panel I get this:
[error. Cause: unknown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u20IC.jpg)

---

On the other hand:

- Any spock tests in android modules run fine.
- All my java tests in all my modules run fine.
- All my tests (spock and java) run fine when running them from outside AS using gradle *(gradlew clean test)*.

---

My setup:

- gradle **v4.1**
- android gradle plugin **v3.0.0**
- java version compatibility **v1.8**
- in my java modules i use the **[gradle groovy plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html)**
- in my android modules i use the **[groovy android gradle plugin](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin)**

---

A few things I tried after searching in both google and here:

- changing the android gradle plugin back to v2.3.3 and gradle to v3.3
- trying to copy all groovy classes to build/classes/java/test

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have your spock tests in `src/test/groovy` or `src/test/java`?

Comment: In `src/test/groovy`.

Comment: I found [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65712492) in google issue tracker which contains a temporary workaround. I tried it and it works on me too resulting in the same problem that the reporter has: *class already exists*.

Comment: @le0nidas, I suggest you star the issue to mark that you are affected by it

Comment: I didn't know i could do that. thank you.

Comment: @le0nidas try this fix instead, which workaround the problem while avoiding the "class already exists" problem.

Try to add this to build.gradle

    sourceSets {
        test {
            groovy {
                // Workaround for issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65712492
                // regarding to "Class not found .... Empty test suite" issue
                outputDir = sourceSets.test.java.outputDir
            }
        }
    }


And yes, the last comment in that thread is me.

Comment: @thinkpanda That worked find. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

So this is more of a workaround than an actual solution but it should give you your debugger back which is probably 90% of the value anyway:

You can run your test suite like:

```
./gradlew <module>:test --debug-jvm
```

And the jvm running your tests will suspend until a debugger attaches.

From Android Studio bring up the action chooser by pressing `ctrl + shift + a` (on linux anyway, check the equivalent for your OS) and select:

> Attach to local process...

Once Android Studio attaches the tests will begin running.

The `--debug-jvm` flag can be used together with `--tests` to debug an individual test:

```
./gradlew <module>:test --tests fully.qualified.test.Test --debug-jvm
```

Comment: `cmd + shift + a` on a mac